# Between 12 noon and 1 PM there are 2 instants when the hr hand and the min hand of a clock are at right anglesThe difference between these 2 instants:

Tags: geometry

Between 12 noon and 1 PM when the minute hand is somewhere between 15 and 20 at that time and when the minute hand is somewhere between 45 and 50 at that two instants we get right angles .But I can't calculate the exact difference of minutes between these two instants.

Answer (score 3):

*As seen by someone who lives on the hour hand*, the minute hand rotates with constant speed, making $11$ revolutions in $12$ hours.

We're looking for how long time it takes for the minute hand to make *one half* of a revolution relative to the hour hand. This will be
$$ \frac12 \times \frac{12\;\rm h}{11} = \frac{720\;\rm m}{22} = 32.727272\ldots \;\text{minutes} $$

Comment: Realised my mistake

Answer (score 0):

θ = 30h - 5.5m (where h stands for hour and m stands for minutes)

put the hour that is 12 in the equation and put θ =90 and θ= 270 as both of them suggest a 90 degree from both directions.

then find out the difference between the minutes, and you have the answer.

p.s.: its an uga question, right?

Comment: Yes, it was there in today's ISI UGA Paper

Comment: how was the paper overall?

Comment: how did you fare?

Comment: I don't think we're allowed to talk here. Why don't you join [this room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76340/jee-high-school-maths-problems)?

Comment: It was not much difficult.

Comment: the formula was taught to us by our MAT teacher. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the clock as a circle.

The hour hand starts at $0$ degrees and goes forward $\frac{1}{2}$degrees every minute.

The minute hand starts at $0$ and goes forward $6$ degrees per minute.

You are therefore solving for $k$ in $$6k=\frac{1}{2}k+90$$
and
$$6k=\frac{1}{2}k+270$$
For which you get $k= \frac{180}{11}=16.\dot{3}\dot{6}$, and $k=\frac{540}{11}=49.\dot{0}\dot{9}$

The difference between these is the time you require, or $32.\dot{7}\dot{2}$ minutes.

Comment: If it takes 16.36 minutes from noon until the angle between the two hands has increased by 90 degrees (which I agree with) then why would it take less than 2 times 16.36 minutes for the angle to increase by 180 degrees more? It looks like you're assuming that the two hands will coincide again at 1 PM exactly -- but at that time the hour hand will still be 1/12 of a circle ahead of the minute hand.

Comment: Agreed. Just saw the mistake.